# Oracle: How to extract XML data from attributes in table

Tags: xml-parsing, oracle12c, xmltype, xmltable

I have a table whit XmlType attributes as follow

```
<data>
    <subdata name='FIRST'>AAA</subdata>
    <subdata name='SECOND'>BBB</subdata>
    <subdata name='THIRD'>CCC</subdata>
    ...
</data>
```

I want to extract the XML to obtain the following result:

```
----------------------------
| FIRST   | SECOND  | THIRD
|---------|---------|-------
| AAA     | BBB     | CCC
----------------------------
```

Any idea? 
I want to add that I know the structure of the result table but every element is optionally in the xml.

```
<data>
        <subdata name='FIRST'>AAA</subdata>
        <subdata name='SECOND'>BBB</subdata>
        <subdata name='THIRD'>CCC</subdata>
        ...
    </data>
<data>

        <subdata name='SECOND'>EEE</subdata>
        <subdata name='THIRD'>DDD</subdata>
        ...
    </data>
```

---

```
| FIRST   | SECOND  | THIRD
|---------|---------|-------
| AAA     | BBB     | CCC
|              | EEE      | DDD
----------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try to do it like this:

```sql
SELECT 
  ExtractValue(Value(p),'/data/subdata[@name="FIRST"]/text()') as name1
, ExtractValue(Value(p),'/data/subdata[@name="SECOND"]/text()') as name2
, ExtractValue(Value(p),'/data/subdata[@name="THIRD"]/text()') as name3
FROM TABLE(XMLSequence(Extract(xmltype('<doc><data><subdata name="FIRST">AAA</subdata><subdata name="SECOND">BBB</subdata><subdata name="THIRD">CCC</subdata></data><data><subdata name="SECOND">EEE</subdata><subdata name="THIRD">DDD</subdata></data></doc>')
      ,'/doc/data'))) p
```